# Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 can't receive incoming calls

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, calls

After updating to version 2.3.7 of Android the device can't receive calls.
Although it can call. The caller to my device is said to line was busy always, it happens from any kind of callers. Need to note, that incoming calls are saved to log, but without any notifications.

I played with Profiles, WIFI settings, but it didn't help.
baseband version: S5830XWKS2

Comment: Might be the update borked some configuration data. If you don't get a more useful answer, you might consider a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) (be aware this will delete all your data and the apps you've installed, too).

Answer (score 0):

Under "Settings" then "call settings" in gingerbread there are two settings that might be doing this. 1 call forwarding. this might be referring incoming calls to a dead number. 2 Call rejection. This could be rejecting your calls - just adjust the options set.

If you have a new phones but amended its 'birth' number to the original number you used on the old network this might have something to do with it too. I did once have a phone which in certain situations remembered its original number which was by then not live on any network- just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP's own comments ([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41741/samsung-galaxy-ace-gt-s5830-cant-receive-incoming-calls#comment56438_41747), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41741/samsung-galaxy-ace-gt-s5830-cant-receive-incoming-calls#comment56439_41747)) on [a deleted answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41747/44325):

> So, I solved: clearing all possible kind of caches (Dalvik cache including) in root mode (enter it by pressing menu + power buttons until menu appears) helps me.
>
> I installed OS from http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=cooper&type=stable